# Overriding Weak ISR Handler from Assembly to C++ doesn't compile any code

Tags: c++, c, gcc, arm, isr

I am writing code for embedded programming on an ARM 32-bit based SAM D51 microprocessor using the IDE SEGGER Studio. I'm new to embedded programming and am writing my first interrupt.

The vector table with a dummy handler is written in ARM assembly, here's one example, the following code is auto-generated on project creation but marked as weak so it can be overridden in C/C++

```
  ldr r0, =__stack_end__
  mov sp, r0
  bl SystemInit
  b _start

  .thumb_func
  .weak SystemInit
SystemInit:
  bx lr
```

Anywhere I read online says to simply add a C/C++ function with identical name and it's magically used by the linker because it's not marked as weak. Below is where I'm overriding it.

```cpp
void SystemInit()
{
  printf("Here");
}
```

However the debugger states that it can't place a breakpoint there because there's no code and in the disassembler it reveals that the entire function has been made into a comment with no code.

I've tried other functions including many of the handler functions but they all do the exact same thing and I have no idea why.

I've even tried forward declaring a weak function and then overriding it or marking the function as volatile. Here is my latest attempt but with the same result:

```cpp
extern void __attribute__((weak)) SystemInit();

void SystemInit()
{
  printf("Here");
}
```

and another attempt

```cpp
volatile void SystemInit()
{
  printf("Here");
}
```

They all end in no code being generated for the function and it appearing as a comment in disassembly.

Comment: `extern "C" {` !

Comment: Wow, I've seen extern "C" here and there when I was learning C++ but I didn't know what it did so I never looked into it. As soon as I added it before the function it's all working now. Thank you very much @KamilCuk and for the very fast response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identifiers in C++ source files have their names mangled. The resulting linker function name is different from `SystemInit`. To stop C++ compiler from mangling the function name, declare the function with `extern "C"`. That way generated function name will match the function name expected by the linker.

Comment: Thank you for the help, this was the answer.